# How to store form input data into a jquery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, forms

I'm new to Jquery and need a solution for a challenge.

What I need precisely is to store the inputs of a HTML form into an existing array. Do you know the Jquery logic to do this?

Here is a sample of the HTML that is the focus of this inquiry.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="inputform" value""idkyet></input>
</form>
```

Example of how I'd like this to work:

User types name into form and clicks submit. That name is now stored into an existing array.

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried [$.serializeArray](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray)?

Comment: This question is too broad. What are you doing with the array? What have you tried already? What research have you done? What problems are you having solving it?

Comment: Try not to overload on us. I'v evaluated my question before submitting it and have asked precisely what I've needed to ask to obtain the answer required. This question has been answered by another member. Everyone has done their part. Its okay now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
yourExistingArrayThatIsDefinedSomewhere.push($("#inputform").val())
console.log(yourExistingArrayThatIsDefinedSomewhere); //should show all previously pushed values
```

Note that you should add the code above to an event handler of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="inputform"> <input type="button" value="submit" id="submitform">
```

JS:

```
var your_array = [];
$("#submitform").click(function(){
  your_array.push($("#inputform").push());
  alert(your_array);
});
```

i think you should do a bit of studing yourself instead of just posting anything here.

Comment: you're the sum of noone to tell people that.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the value of the input in jQuery and adding it to an array would be something like this :

```js
var array = [];

$("#inputform").change(function() {
    array.push(this.value);
    alert(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="inputform" value=""></input>
</form>
```

For example, here each time the value of the input changes, it will add it to the array.

Comment: Without implementing something like a `preventDefault()` in the submit handler, clicking an input or button with `type="submit"` in a `<form>` will cause a page refresh. Click your submit button and check out what happens.